# Building a complex SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having a hard time getting a complex SQLite query to output the data I want.

I have the following tables in a database (simplified and tweaked for the purpose of the question).

### Conferences

```
ID | Name        | Date     | main_contact | Conference ID
1  | BH 13       | 01/02/13 | 123          | 4534534
2  | HITB        | 03/05/13 | 345          | 5345435
3  | Troopers    | 04/04/13 | 666          | 6545345
4  | DEF CON 13  | 08/08/13 | 123          | 5345633
5  | APP Sec     | 10/10/13 | 345          | 3456789
6  | BH 14       | 01/02/14 | 123          | 4534534
7  | DEF CON 14  | 08/08/14 | 666          | 5345633
```

### Attendees

```
ID | Name Row | Conference ID
1  | 2        | 6545345
2  | 4        | 6545345
3  | 5        | 6545345
4  | 1        | 4534534
5  | 2        | 4534534
6  | 3        | 5345435
7  | 1        | 5345633
8  | 4        | 5345633
9  | 2        | 3456789
10 | 3        | 3456789
11 | 5        | 3456789
```

### Name

```
ID | Name    | Fallback_Name | Contact_id
1  | Tom     | T. Carnes     | 123
2  | Matt    | M. Dotes      | 879
3  | NULL    | J. Barnes     | 345
4  | Trevor  | NULL          | 666
5  | Sam     | NULL          | 426
```

As you may (or may not) notice, the conference ID is reused for the same conference that happens on a different year.

SO what I want to do is build a query the creates an output as follows;

### Output

```
Conference Name | Date     | Main Contact | Attendees
BH 13           | 01/02/13 | Tom          | Tom, Matt
HITB            | 03/05/13 | J. Barnes    | J. Barnes
Troopers        | 04/04/13 | Trevor       | Matt, Trevor, Sam
DEF CON 13      | 08/08/13 | Tom          | Tom, Trevor
APP Sec         | 10/10/13 | J. Barnes    | Matt, J. Barnes, Sam
BH 14           | 01/02/14 | Tom          | Tom, Matt
DEF CON 14      | 08/08/14 | Trevor       | Tom, Trevor
```

So, couple of points. If Name is blank, use fallback_name, and join all attendee names in one column.

Any help on this would be great; I keep getting close, but can't quite get it right.

Just to add, I didn't create this database so I know its not the best designed thing, I just want to query it.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: You don't seem to have any way to distinguish the attendees by year for the conferences.  The third column in the `Attendees` table should refer to the `Conferences.Id`, not `Conferences.ConferenceId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SQLite supports [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) this isn't too hard to accomplish:

```
select 
  c.name as "Conference Name",
  c.Date, 
  coalesce(n2.name, n2."fallback_name") as "Main Contact",
  group_concat(coalesce(n.name, n."fallback_name"), ', ') as Attendees
from conferences c
inner join attendees a on c."Conference ID" = a."Conference ID"
inner join name n on n.id = a."Name Row"
inner join name n2 on n2.Contact_id = c."main_contact"
group by c.name 
order by c.date
```

Note that the order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d26b6/2) using SQLite (SQL.js).